# Android sqlite InsertHelper

Tags: android

i have arraylist of custom object(title and id) arraylist of size 7000+ ,i have created it from the json ,then i need to insert it in db,for this i have using insertHelper ,it seems faster ,but i need to complete the insertion with in 10 to 15 s

Comment: What is the exact thing that you want to perform? Can you explain to more briefly so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

while inserting into the arraylist , just create one more thread to insert into the sqlitedatabase database.

Comment: i have mapping the json to model class ,it's single line of code